# Changing a view's bounds doesn't change where it draws

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, bounds, cgrect

In `viewDidLoad`, I create a `UIView` at 100,100 with a size of 200x200, then change it's bounds to have an origin of -100,-100. I had supposed that this would either move the entire view back to the top left, or only draw a smaller rectangle for the intersection of the frame and bounds. It didn't affect the drawn-into area at all.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200);
    greenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [greenView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(-100, -100, 200, 200);
    [greenView setBounds:bounds];
    [greenView setClipsToBounds:YES];
    [greenView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeRedraw];

    [self.view addSubview:greenView];
}
```

The frame and bounds log as follows:

```
Frame: {{100, 100}, {200, 200}}
Bounds: {{-100, -100}, {200, 200}}
```

I thought that a view only draws into it's bounds rect. What am I missing about views and bounds? Why doesn't changing my view's bounds change where it draws?

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: Change the view's `frame`, not `bounds`

Comment: @rmaddy I know that's what I _should_ do, but the purpose here isn't to move the view, it's to understand more about views and bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Maddy, for your use case you just change the `frame`. Here is what happens behind the scenes:

Changing the frame is like changing `bounds` *and* `center` of the view. So if you want to use `bounds`, also change the `center`. Please note that the `size` of the `frame` is not necessarily the same as the `size of the`bounds` because the view might be rotated.

Therefore, your statement "*I thought that a view only draws into it's bounds rect.*" is if not incorrect at least not precise enough. If you rotate your `{200,200}` view by 45 degrees, its `bounds` would still be `{200,200}`, but its `frame.size` will be `200 * sqrt(2)` for both width and height. The `bounds` refer to the view's *own* coordinate system, the `frame` to that of the *superview*.

Answer (score 0):

What Mundi said, but I would like to add, if you ever thought why *bounds* even existed, it makes a lot of sense when scrolling. An **NSClipView**'s bounds of an NSScrollView is the part of the NSScrollView's document view that is visible. So scrollView.contentView.bounds changes as you scroll but scrollView.contentView.frame **obviously** does not.